# Postgres - conditional update an indicator variable based on a second table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, conditional-statements, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to conditionally populate an indicator (1/0) column in my original table (tracedetail) based on whether the rows in my original table fall within a certain date range (specified in my second table - bondmaturity).

Specifically, my second table provides an ID variable (cusip_id) and two columns that specify a start and end date (start_dt, end_dt). I need to populate the 'ontherun' variable in my first table with a '1' if the 'trd_exctn_dt' date variable falls within this date range for a particular ID, '0' if it doesn't.

I have tried numerous methods and from reading a number of threads think that using a CASE option may be the correct method but can not get this to work. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Many thanks.

```
UPDATE tracedetail a
  SET on_the_run = 
  (CASE WHEN 
      (a.cusip_id = b.cusip_id)
      AND (a.trd_exctn_dt::date >= b.start_dt::date)
      AND  (b.end_dt::date >= a.trd_exctn_dt::date)
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM 
  (SELECT 
      cusip_id,
      start_dt,
      end_dt
   FROM bondmaturity)
  AS b;
```

Apologies - please ignore this question. I believe that I the correct way to answer the problem is to run the following:

```
UPDATE tracedetail a
SET on_the_run = 1
FROM    (SELECT cusip_id,
                start_dt,
                end_dt
        FROM bondmaturity) AS b
WHERE   a.cusip_id = b.cusip_id
AND     a.trd_exctn_dt::date >= b.start_dt::date
AND     b.end_dt::date >= a.trd_exctn_dt::date;
```

Following this I ran an update to populate NULL values with the value '0'

```
UPDATE tracedetail
SET on_the_run = 
    CASE WHEN on_the_run IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE on_the_run END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `EXISTS` subquery condition which will return a boolean type (TRUE/FALSE) value. You'll have to cast the value into the corresponding integer value (1/0). It would be a better design if the `on_the_run` field was already of type boolean rather than integer.

```
UPDATE tracedetail a
  SET on_the_run = EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
     FROM bondmaturity b
    WHERE a.cusip_id = b.cusip_id
      AND a.trd_exctn_dt::date >= b.start_dt::date
      AND b.end_dt::date >= a.trd_exctn_dt::date
  )::integer;
```

You might consider adding a trigger to one or both of your tables so that the `on_the_run` field will automatically be updated any time any of your date fields are updated.